# Xamarin Unified API: Native library binding: NSUInteger vs. enum

Tags: ios, binding, enums, xamarin, native

I am binding to a native Objective-C library with the help of a Binding Project in Xamarin.

Everything works fine. Now I migrated my solution to the Xamarin Unified API and to 32 AND 64 bit and after a lot of work, it works OK again.

Although everything is working, I am wondering how `enum`s work with the 32/64 environment.

In Objective-C I have:

`typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, ...` which should be backed up by 32 bits under a 32 bit environment and by 64 bit under a 64 bit environment.

In `StructsAndEnums.cs` I have just a normal `enum` for the above `NS_OPTIONS-NSUInteger`. But an enum (without further specification) is always 32 bit in C#. How can that binding work under a 64 bit environment?

Is there any intelligent mechanism (at compile or run time) that recognizes when a method within a native library wants a 64 bit parameter (and can "convert" the 32 bit enum to a 64 bit)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Use a 64-bit type (long or ulong) for the enum, and decorate it with the [Native] attribute:

```
[Native]
public enum MyEnum : long
{
    // ...
}
```

And then you can use the enum in your ApiDefinition.cs, and the binding code will automatically generate the right thing.

Note that you can't use these enums in P/Invokes, since those aren't special-cased (in those cases can use the native types nint/nunit instead).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question was rather "Is there ALREADY any intelligent machanism"? Because, it is working with normal enum (without [Native] and long). My question was: Why does it work?

Comment: The `[Native]` attribute (and having a 64-bit backing type) is required for it to work properly. If it seems to work properly without it, you're just getting lucky.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. So I will add [Native] attribute and set the enum type to ulong. Is this documented somewhere?